# First time React-native: error: code: 400, details: Object, message: Invalid value at requests[0].image.source

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native

I have a project where I need to make an app; choose from gallery or take a picture, send it to cloud and detect objects there. I used this tutorial: https://medium.com/crowdbotics/how-to-build-a-real-time-logo-detection-app-with-react-native-google-vision-api-and-crowdbotics-9ed65fbcd15, code: https://github.com/amandeepmittal/google-vision-rn-demo/blob/master/App.js. But as can't use Expo as a requirement here is my app.js:

```
 import React from "react";
import {View, Text, Image, Button, StyleSheet, ScrollView, ActivityIndicator, FlatList} from "react-native";
import * as ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import * as uuid from 'uuid';

import firebase from './config/firebase';

export default class App extends React.Component{
  state = {
    image: null,
    uploading: false,
        googleResponse: null,
  };

  submitToGoogle = async () => {
    try {
      this.setState({ uploading: true });
      let { image } = this.state;
      let body = JSON.stringify({
        requests: [
          {
            features: [
              { type: 'LABEL_DETECTION', maxResults: 10 },
              { type: 'LANDMARK_DETECTION', maxResults: 5 },
              { type: 'FACE_DETECTION', maxResults: 5 },
              { type: 'LOGO_DETECTION', maxResults: 5 },
              { type: 'TEXT_DETECTION', maxResults: 5 },
              { type: 'DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION', maxResults: 5 },
              { type: 'SAFE_SEARCH_DETECTION', maxResults: 5 },
              { type: 'IMAGE_PROPERTIES', maxResults: 5 },
              { type: 'CROP_HINTS', maxResults: 5 },
              { type: 'WEB_DETECTION', maxResults: 5 }
            ],
            image: {
              source: {
                imageUri: image
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      });
      let response = await fetch(
        'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=' +
         apiKey,
        {
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          method: 'POST',
          body: body
        }
      );
      let responseJson = await response.json();
      console.log(responseJson);
      this.setState({
        googleResponse: responseJson,
        uploading: false
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  handleChoosePhoto = async () => {
    const options = {
      //noData: true
    };
    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
      console.log("response", response);
      if(response.uri){
        try {
          this.setState({ image: response ,uploading: true });
          uploadUrl = uploadImageAsync(response.uri);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
          alert('Upload failed');
        } finally {
          this.setState({ uploading: false });
        }
      }
    });
  };

  handleTakePhoto = async () =>{
    ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, response => {
      console.log("response", response);
      if(response.uri){
        try {
          this.setState({ image: response ,uploading: true });
          uploadUrl = uploadImageAsync(response.uri);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
          alert('Failed to take a photo');
        } finally {
          this.setState({ uploading: false });
        }
      }
    });
  };

  render(){
    const {image} = this.state;
    return(
      <View style = {{flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center"}}>
        {image && (
          <View>
          <Image
            source = {{uri: image.uri}}
            style = {{width: 300, height: 300}}
          />
          <Button style={{ marginBottom: 10 }} onPress={() => this.submitToGoogle()} title="Analyze!"/>
          </View>
        )}
        <Button title = "Choose From Gallery" onPress = {this.handleChoosePhoto}/>
        <Button title = "Take a Photo" onPress = {this.handleTakePhoto}/>
      </View>
    );
  }

}

async function uploadImageAsync(uri) {
    const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function() {
            resolve(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            reject(new TypeError('Network request failed'));
        };
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.open('GET', uri, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    });

    const ref = firebase
        .storage()
        .ref()
        .child(uuid.v4());
    const snapshot = await ref.put(blob);

    blob.close();

    return await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
}
```

I would also like to add that images I sent get to fire base without problem.[Here is a screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcGHS.jpg). I have looked all over but could not find anything helpfull.

Message:
{"error": {"code": 400, "details": [[Object]], "message": "Invalid value at 'requests[0].image.source' (image_uri), Starting an object on a scalar field", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}